# How to do A/B testing with Marathon and Mesos?

Tags: apache-mesos

How to do [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) with Marathon and Mesos?

We're currently investigating an enterprise solution called vamp, but if there are any good open source solutions, that'd be great to know.